# How can I display y axis titles horizontally in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, axis, amcharts

Can anyone please help me in displaying the title of my Y axis horizontally? Also I want the graph to occupy full X axis (entire X axis). Below is the code I am using:

```
function createXYZchart() {
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = dataXYZ; //data source
    chart.categoryField = "month"; //data provider X-Axis

    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
    chart.angle = 60;
    chart.depth3D = 5;
    chart.columnWidth = 0.85;

    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.dashLength = 10;
    valueAxis.autoGridCount = false;
    valueAxis.minimum = 90;
    valueAxis.maximum = 100;
    valueAxis.gridCount=5;
    valueAxis.labelFunction = formatLabel;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the vertical value axis title display horizontally use its [`titleRotation`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#titleRotation) property: (set it to 0 - or zero rotation)

```
valueAxis.title = "Y axis";
valueAxis.titleRotation = 0;
```

To make the graph extend the full width of the plot area, set `startOnAxis` on your [`categoryAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#startOnAxis) to `true`:

```
categoryAxis.startOnAxis = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But this is not working for me . Y axis is being displayed on left of the graph and also nothing change in my x axis :(

Comment: What version of amCharts are you running?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. legend.position="right" was overriding it..  Thank you

Comment: I need one more help.. On clicking titles, graph(column) for that title disappears and clicking again it appears. title will be enabled in the beginning . how can i keep it disabled so that graph for that title also disappears until i click title .

Comment: Do you mean you want the graph to be hidden by default?

Comment: Not entire graph should be hidden, graph should be hidden for rest titles. only one title and and respective column should be enabled in the beginning

Comment: To disable one graph (line or otherwise), set it's `hidden` property to `true`: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#hidden